# Swift - Update labels in realtime

Tags: swift, dispatch-queue

I have a complex set of maths that takes several seconds (and that's on the faster iPhones). To keep the user interested and believe the program isn't taking a nap I need to update the labels/numbers in realtime.

Historically I would have used:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {...
```

But that gives Thread 1 errors when run nowadays.
So I am using:

```
    DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: {
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            self.dateLabel.text = date1Formatter.string(from: newDate!)
            // etc
        }
     })
```

Surprise, surprise this isn't updating the numbers in realtime, just at the end of the cycle. How do I "sync" it?

Comment: Use 'async' instead of 'sync'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call main.sync at all.
Just call DispatchQueue.main.async Ashley Mills says:

```
    DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.dateLabel.text = date1Formatter.string(from: newDate!)
            // etc
        }
     })
```

Comment: What's the point of the intermediate queue? Just calling `DispatchQueue.main.async` is enough (as main is already a serial queue)

Comment: It's needed if he wants to use it inside loop and not block the execution. If not - you are right.

Comment: Just calling `DispatchQueue.main.async` won't block execution

Comment: Great so it's now off the main queue but again the labels don't update until the loop has completed. Any ideas?

Comment: Have changed with these updates but the screen still isn't updated until the loop finished not at the end of each pass?

Comment: Have put the DispatchQueue around the originating loop and not the calc function itself and it worked - many thanks. let queue1 = DispatchQueue(label: "test1", qos: DispatchQoS.userInteractive)
        DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: {
            queue1.sync {
                for day in 1...365 {
                    self.calculate(day)
                }
            }
        })